# How can I append null in list when particular parameter is absent for some lines while iterating through log file using urlparser

Tags: python, urllib, urlparse

I want my file to get parsed by url but some of the url have missing parameters and when I am iterating through lines of log I am getting error of missing parameter.
I need to append blank or null value into in parse list so that I can transform it into data frame

My Data File : log file

```
"GET /pixel.gife=heartbeat&creative_id=33548&in_view_time=290"
"GET/pixel.gife=heartbeat&creative_id=33548&in_view_time=23988"
"GET /pixel.gif?e=heartbeat&creative_id=33548&in_view_time=19183"
"GET /pixel.gif?e=ad_load&creative_id=33548"
```

I want Output as :

```
   E |  Creative ID | IN VIEW TIME

   heartbeat   33548    290

   heartbeat 33548 23988

   ad_load 33548 null
```

My Code:

```
parselist = []
for eachline in log.readlines():
    ip_regex = re.findall(r'(\d{18})', eachline)
    date = re.findall(r'([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})',eachline)
    url = eachline
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    parselist.append(ip_regex)
    parselist.append(date)
    parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['e'])
    parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['account_id'])
    parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['impression_id'])
    parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['campaign_id'])
    parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['creative_id'])
    parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['in_view_time'])
```

Error I am getting as in_view_time parameter is missing in third line:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-405c1bfb329e> in <module>()
     12     parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['campaign_id'])
     13     parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['creative_id'])
---> 14     parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['in_view_time'])

KeyError: 'in_view_time'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try` and `except`:

```
parselist = []
for eachline in log.readlines():
    ip_regex = re.findall(r'(\d{18})', eachline)
    date = re.findall(r'([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})',eachline)
    url = eachline
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    parselist.append(ip_regex)
    parselist.append(date)
    try:
        parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['e'])
    except:
        parselist.append('Null')
    try:
        parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['account_id'])
    except:
        parselist.append('Null')
    try:
        parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['impression_id'])
    except:
        parselist.append('Null')
    try:
        parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['campaign_id'])
    except:
        parselist.append('Null')
    try:
        parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['creative_id'])
    except:
        parselist.append('Null')
    try:
        parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['in_view_time'])
    except:
        parselist.append('Null')
```

Or, in a more compact way:

```
parselist = []
for eachline in log.readlines():
    ip_regex = re.findall(r'(\d{18})', eachline)
    date = re.findall(r'([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})',eachline)
    url = eachline
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    parselist.append(ip_regex)
    parselist.append(date)

    for key in ['e','account_id','impression_id','campaign_id','creative_id','in_view_time']:
        try:
            parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)[key])
        except:
            parselist.append('Null')
```

As a suggestion, instead of `'Null'` you can append `None`.

Answer (score -1):

1. Why are you creating a list (where you're losing key and just
   storing values)?
2. If you are just interested in the values then you
   can simply write following:

```py
for v in urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query).values():
    parselist.append(v)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18234094)

Comment: fyi, dictionary (which urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query) is), can be checked using
`if 'in_view_time' in urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query):
    parselist.append(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['in_view_time'])
else:
    parselist.append('Null')
`
You can do this in Diego's compact version too.